# Is there a word or phrase for someone that is propped up as the bad example of something, even though others are guilty the same?

Tags: phrase-requests, epithet-requests

I was planning on using whipping boy but it seems that means more like a scapegoat (ie someone who is innocent but made to take the blame for others). Moreover, I want something that means that everyone seems to point to one particular person as the bad example and turn a blind eye to the same behavior in others. The issue is more with reputation or perception from an outside group than guilt per se, but I don't want to suggest that the example person is innocent. The context is history.

Comment: Why don't you like the word you used? See [scapegoat](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scapegoat) "a person who is blamed for something that someone else has done: *The captain was made a scapegoat for the team's failure.*"

Comment: Because it suggests innocence of the person being used as a proxy for the guilt of others, and I want to suggest that both are equally guilty, but only one gets made an example of.

Comment: Not really, since no real solution was found, but thank you. What I am aiming to express is more about how the public or an outside group props up this one person as an especially bad actor when others did the same thing. Mafia language like "fall guy" is more about inter-group organization....

Comment: I added a new answer to that duplicate.

Comment: What’s wrong with “to make an example of,” which does not show up in the duplicate?

Comment: @Xanne it's okay...very close... but to make an example of suggests to me that that example person deserves it somehow even if the punishment is not equal.  My idea is more like the opposite of a golden boy... someone who other people enjoy calling out as somehow bad when they were doing what everyone else was doing.

Comment: This is peculiar because the question has caused a new answer to the duplicate, and while I haven’t written mine up there, I believe it is likely the most appropriate.  But they cannot be selected there, although they could be up  voted.